# Trying to suppress mail library echos by ob_start and ob_end_clean

Tags: php

REF : [PHP: Suppress output within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486181/php-suppress-output-within-a-function)

Using the method suggested at the above link, i tried to suppress the output of mail function in PHPMAILER. But seems it suppresses the mail itself. What's the alternative to suppress the echos by mail library, so that a single echo $returnValue can be achieved ?

```
ob_start();
    include('mail.php');   //<< USING PHPMAILER 
ob_end_clean();

echo $returnValue
```

Comment: it depends what mail.php is doing - if it is printing your mail to the screen then your OutputBuffer will catch it - that's what they do. Are you saying that $returnValue is something set inside your mail.php that isn't accessible in the parent scope?

Comment: including phpmailer should not do *any* output. Your question makes not much sense I must admit.

Comment: it's echoing much output before $returnValue . It's not a normal mail function. It's a file from phpmailer library.

Answer (score 1):

ob_end_clean trashes whatever's been buffered. If you want to output what you've captured in the buffers, you need

```
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;
```

That being said, output buffering will not affect sending an email, because that's done purely in the background and not subject to the buffering. the ob_*() buffering only captures output from the script, e.g. anything from echo/print calls. mail() itself does not use either of those to generate/send the mail.

Comment: I got the impression that something in mail was Excepting to the screen and that's what he was trying to buffer - the exception

Comment: @kristopher, Ya. Tht's what the problem is. It's echoing out mail result ( A lot of data that talks about mail header and other details). I want to suppress that. As it get's echoed before $returnValue, and creates problem in the application.

Comment: I don't know what mail.php does, what you have above should grab all output - but if you're outputting errors, well, you won't catch those separately. do you have a link to a git of the phpmailer script that I could take a look at?