# How to supress echoes from functions?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Suppress output within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486181/php-suppress-output-within-a-function)

**I am using multiple php scripts.."**

That include libraries I need.  The thing is that they are designed to give an output to the browser in the forms of `echo` and `print` or `print_r`

However I need to use them and not display anything for all I care is the operation they do. Is there any way I can supress the output those functions give without modifying source code?

Comment: You mean from client side?

Comment: @BackinaFlash nope, server side. I'm calling the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ob_start](http://ch2.php.net/ob_start) and [ob_clean](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

```
//start of your script
ob_start();

/*some library stuff*/

// clean up the buffer
ob_end_clean();

/*your stuff*/
```

Comment: `ob_end_clean` not clean_end ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start), and just discard the buffer:

```
ob_start();

function_that_prints_stuff_1();
function_that_prints_stuff_2();

// Done with the printing functions, discard the buffer:
ob_end_clean();
```