# Laravel/Blade calls echo when referencing this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

#### Problem (MRP)

I have a `.blade.php`-file that references a php-function which should return some html.

```
{!! $template->render() !!}
```

The `render()`-function uses `$this` and then returns a string.

```
class Template extends Model {
    function render() : string {
        $this->someEmptyFunc();
        return "Some String";
    }

    function someEmptyFunc() {}
}
```

`someEmptyFunction()` doesn't echo anything, and every time that `$this` gets referenced, this object gets echoed as if I had called `echo var_dump($this);`

#### Info

- The Template class is a Laravel-Model-class
- The code above is a minimal example that produces the error for me.
- I dont really want to avoid the bug by [exploiting the output-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486181/php-suppress-output-within-a-function).